Prefill dropboxes based on user selection from prior page
I cannot get the drop-boxes to fill from the users selection on the prior page - can someone help?
Prior page code saving the values:
export function button43_click(event) {
        session.setItem("statehome",$w('#dropdownstate').value);
        session.setItem("lakehome",$w('#dropdownlake').value);
        wixLocation.to("https://www.laketoads.com/import-791")

Current page code trying to set the default value to the user's selections:
import {session} from 'wix-storage';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {

    $w('#stateDropdown').options = [];
    $w('#lakeDropdown').options = [];

    $w('#stateDropdown').onChange((event) => {
        populateLakeData(event.target.value);
    });

    populateStateData();

    const selectedstate = session.getItem("statehome");
    $w("#stateDropdown").value = selectedstate;
    const selectedlake = session.getItem("lakehome");
    $w("#lakeDropdown").value = selectedlake;
});

Can anyone help? - I've tried both local and session code and am stuck.

Use the dataset setFilter() function instead of refreshing. Set the filter to the values in the dropdowns. You will need to refilter when the dropdowns change as well.

I have figured out how to prefill the dropdowns on the 2nd page - now I just need help refreshing my repeater based on these entries - any suggestions?
$w.onReady(function () {
const selectedstate = session.getItem("statehome");
$w("#stateDropdown").value = selectedstate;

const selectedlake = session.getItem("lakehome");
$w("#lakeDropdown").value = selectedlake;

$w("#dynamicDataset").refresh()

$w('#stateDropdown').onChange((event) => {
    populateLakeData(event.target.value);
});

populateStateData();

});
